# How to set a correct layout param just like FrameLayout in React-Native layout?

Tags: android, react-native, android-mapview, android-framelayout

What I wanna do is creating a frame layout just like android's FrameLayout and I have failed several times reasonably. That's why I am here.

Expected scene:
       1: Creating a map view in the bottom layer.(Native component)
       2: Showing a marker on the map view. (Native component as above)
       3: Placing a search widget on the top frame.(React component)

Here is the layout in a react-native page, named page.js:

```
<MapLayout>
    <TextInput style={ marginTop: 20, borderRadius: 5, padding: 5, marginLeft: 16, marginRight: 16, width:100, height: 100 ,backgroundColor:'red'}} placeholder='search'></TextInput>
</MapLayout>
```

Note:MapLayout is a native component from android, which extends from FrameLayout and can be exported to React-Native. There is a MapView widget in the bottom layer as a background, probably with a overlay on the map.

Give me a hand please. Thanks for all kindness first.

Answer (score 0):

you can do frame layout using this way

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Animated, View, StyleSheet, Easing, Text } from "react-native";



class A extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
  }

  handleAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      easing: Easing.ease
    }).start();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.layer1} />
        <View style={styles.overLay}>
          <Text>This is an overlay area</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  layer1: {
    height:100,
    backgroundColor: "lightgreen",

  },
  overLay: {
    height: 100,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#00000070",
    position: "absolute",

  }
});

export default A;
```